# How to combine artemis-odb + Glenn Fiedler game loop

Tags: java, libgdx, game-loop, artemis

I want to use artemis (https://github.com/junkdog/artemis-odb) for my game.

Lately I read about Glenn Fiedler's game loop:
http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

So the mentioned game loop has two parts where artemis world.process(); would take place. The integrate part and the render part.

Any ideas how I could accomplish something like this with artemis.

```
while(!quit) {
    .....
    while (accumulator >= dt) {
       world.process("only EntitySystems of group1 or with Components X (INTEGRATE STUFF)");
       ....
    }
    ....
    world.process("only EntitySystems of group2 or with Components Y (RENDER STUFF)");
}
```

Does artemis support this kind of gameloop?

The only solution which comes to my mind right now is:

Set a global static flag which indicates whether its integrate or render process and then exit all `EntitySystem.process(Entity e)` methods when the wrong flag is set. Like this:

```
@Override
protected void process(Entity e) {
    if(GLOBAL.RENDER_TIME) {
        return; // exit cause, this entity should only be processed when it is INTEGRATE TIME
    }   
}
```

Problem with this is that there are iteration over a lot of entities which are not required since the entities do not process anything.

I was thinking about having 2 `Worlds` but I don't think I can easily share same Component instances between `Worlds`, especially when they are pooled objects.

Any idea how to combine artemis-odb  + Glenn Fiedler game loop?

EDIT:
Just figured out I can use `setEnabled()` to disable and enable `EntitySystems`. This will do it for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/junkdog/artemis-odb/wiki/InvocationStrategy

That is what I was looking for

And this is how I implemented it:
https://github.com/TomGrill/logic-render-game-loop